# Saving Firefox tab state for reopening?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

If I have six or seven tabs open in Firefox, and I need to close it down for performance or other reasons, is there a way to save that state of tabs so the next time I open Firefox it'll reopen those tabs?

Comment: Firefox has asked if you want to save tabs by default for a while now.  What version are you running?

Comment: I'm on 3.5.3, so a very recent version.  When I originally set up FireFox I switched off the option of saving tabs when I close-- I'd like it so that it saves the tabs only when I want it to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Main -> "When Firefox Starts" option. You just have to select "Show my windows and tabs from last time".

In some versions of Firefox it is instead menu Tools -> Options -> General -> "When Firefox Starts".

Comment: Sounds great, thank you!  (and to everyone who contributed.)

Answer (score 3):

[**Tab Mix Plus**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/), an add-on for Firefox, has a feature called Session Manager. It will reload the state of all tabs and windows when you restart Firefox.

[image]

I think there is already a session manager in Firefox 3.5 but the version included in Tab Mix Plus is much more advanced.

If you don't need all the features of Tab Mix Plus, there is also a [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/) add-on but I never tried it, as TMP has tons of other features.

Comment: How is TMP's "much more advanced"?

Answer (score 0):

Simply select Exit in the File menu.

Comment: Firefox v3.5.3 here.

Answer (score 0):

I persume you have a pretty old Firefox.

Download the newest one. If you close it, it should tell you if you want to save your tabs. Otherwise look at Preferences.